# Dynamic PixiJS canvas goes wrong after first load in vue app

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vue-router, pixi.js

I'm building a website with Vue.js and use PixiJS to dynamically draw a canvas with data that comes from a big json file. The canvas is generated as a component and used in a view.

Now the first time when I navigate to the view with the canvas, it all looks fine. But when I start navigating between views, the drawing is all messed up, the sprites are all there but it looks all out of place and messy. When I then refresh the page, the canvas looks fine again. Here is an image:

[image]

I'm not sure what the problem is here, but I feel like it's a combination of things. Maybe the 100k line json file I'm working with has something to do with it (the view also feels kind of slow when I interact with it)

This is kind of how my Vue component looks like:

```js
export default {
  name: 'Tree',
  data () {
    return {
      tree: {},
      app: new PIXI.Application()
    }
  },
  beforeMount () {
    this.tree = this.treeStateData
    PIXI.utils.clearTextureCache()
    PIXI.loader.reset()
  },
  mounted () {
    this.loadTree()
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState([
      'treeStateData'
    ])
  },
  methods: {
    loadTree () {
      document.getElementById('tree').appendChild(this.app.view)

      // Load images
      PIXI.loader
        .add('background', require('@/assets/Background1.png'))
        .add('1', require('@/assets/PSGroupBackground1.png'))
      // lots more
        .load(this.drawTree)
    },
    drawTree () {
      const treeData = this.tree

      // Create viewport
      const viewport = new Viewport()
      this.app.stage.addChild(viewport)

      // Here i create some containers

      // Here i work with the data from the json and put stuff in the containers
    }
  }
}
```

The structure of my Vue project is like this:
**Views**

```
views/home.vue    
// Just a view with a link to details.vue

views/details.vue    
// A view that had <tree> component in it
<template>
  <div>
    <tree></tree>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Tree from '@/components/tree'

export default {
  name: 'Details',
  data () {},
  components: {
    Tree
  }
}
</script>
```

**Components**

```
components/tree.vue
// Here is where the tree canvas is generated
```

Anyone got an idea on how to make progress on this? Should i rethink how i do this?

Comment: Try `Object.freeze()` on the json immediately when its loaded (i.e. `const json = Object.freeze(response.data)`.  If that doesn't help, try making none of it reactive, meaning no Vuex, `data`, `props`, storing everything in a module that you import.

Comment: Hi Dan, both don't change what is happening. Might be better to not store it and just import json from '@/data/data.json' and work with that though.

Comment: Yes, that's what my 2nd suggestion was

Comment: Yeah and i tried it also, but doesn't change the situation. But still might be better.. Thanks for the suggestion anyway, if you got more ideas let me know :)

Comment: When you navigate between views, does this stay visible?  Or is it on a separate route / non-existent component that gets re-rendered?  It would be helpful to see the template where it's inserted

Comment: I added some information to the question above with the structure. The component is just visible on this one route. Is this helpfull?

Comment: Yes, maybe the component can be cached.  I posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since everything is working on the first load, caching the component may help when navigating between routes.  It also saves recalculating the PixiJS display each time.

Wrap the `router-view` in a [`keep-alive`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#keep-alive-with-Dynamic-Components) component:

```html
<keep-alive>
   <router-view></router-view>
</keep-alive>
```

Comment: Awesome! This works for now yeah! Performance is still not the best (when navigation/dragging in the viewport), but that is another thing i guess :) If you got any ideas/tips for things i can look into to increase the performance that would be great, but will play around myself as well.

Comment: I'm glad :) One suggestion would be to test whether there is a performance issue using the same PixiJS display in a non-Vue app.  That could help isolate whether the sluggishness is from the browser rendering so much information or if it's related to Vue in some way.

Comment: Thanks Dan. Played around a bit, and found the  problem. Apparently it doesn't like if you create a new PIXI.Graphics() for each connection line, just create it ones and draw all lines on that one. On to the next challenge!